# ¿Cómo usar operadores de segmentación en Onesignal?

Tags: push-notification, operador, onesignal

Muy buen día. 
Estoy implementando una plataforma que usa notificaciones PUSH, para esto estoy utilizando Onesignal.
Según la documentación para realizar una segmentación y enviar una notificación a usuarios en especifico tengo que usar etiquetas con valores únicos, tales como:

```
bool
string
exists
not_exists
```

Los ejemplos son en formato json
En el siguiente ejemplo se evalúa si `is_vip!="true" AND is_admin=="true"`:

```
[
  {"field": "tag", "key": "is_vip", "relation": "!=", "value": "true"},
  {"field": "tag","key": "is_admin", "relation": "=", "value": "true"}
]
```

En el ejemplo siguiente se añade el operador OR para evaluar `is_vio!="true" OR is_admin=="true"`:

```
[
  {"field": "tag", "key": "is_vip", "relation": "!=", "value": "true"},
  {"operator": "OR"}, 
  {"field": "tag","key": "is_admin", "relation": "=", "value": "true"}
]
```

Sin embargo, los ejemplos solo evaluan dos posibilidades y no hay combinaciones como `(is_vip!="true OR (is_admin="true" AND is_premium="true") )`
 Lo que sería teoricamente equivalente a:

```
    [
      {"field": "tag", "key": "is_vip", "relation": "!=", "value": "true"},
      {"operator": "OR"}, 
      {"field": "tag","key": "is_admin", "relation": "=", "value": "true"},
      {"field": "tag","key": "is_premium", "relation": "=", "value": "true"}
    ]
```

Pero no estoy seguro si lo evaliaría como `is_vip!="true" OR is_admin="true" AND is_premium="true"`

O tal vez `((is_vip!="true" OR is_admin="true") AND is_premium="true")`

¿Alguien sabe como se interpreta?

Aquí la documentación sobre esto:
[Documentación Onesignal, crear notificación](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification)

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es la siguiente:

```
[
   {"field": "tag", "key": "is_vip", "relation": "!=", "value": "true"},
   {"field": "tag","key": "is_premium", "relation": "=", "value": "true"},
   {"operator": "OR"}, 
   {"field": "tag","key": "is_admin", "relation": "=", "value": "true"}
]
```

Las comparaciones deben ser completas. Es decir, una condición completa en cada consulta.
El comportamiento si es como lo describí en el mensaje anterior. Pero siempre debe ser lo más exacta posible.